# react redux Promise function to async/await

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following redux function adding new user to my database. It works fine but in event i introduce another call in my `then`, there could be need for extensive catching for everything.
What if we made it into `async` with `try/Catch` to handle all our errors ?
I tried a sample of but kept missing something.
Could someone arrange it for me please. Thanks.

```
export function newUser(values) {
return function(dispatch) {
    const promise = axios.post(URL)

    dispatch(createAdminUsersRequest(promise));

    promise.then(
        user => {
            dispatch(createUsersSuccess(user));
            dispatch(fetchUsers());
            dispatch(switchUserActions(false, false, false));
        },
        function(error) {
            if (error && error.response && error.response.data)
                error = error.response.data;
            if (error && error.data) {
                error = error.data;
            }
            dispatch(createUsersFail(errors(error)));
            setTimeout(() => dispatch(createUsersFail(null)), 6000);
        }
    );

    return promise;
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion on promise to async-await is pretty straightforward. Firstly you declare the function as `async` by adding an `async` keyword to it. Secondly, you use `await` on the promise

```
export function newUser(values) {

    return async function(dispatch) {

        dispatch(createAdminUsersRequest(promise));
        try {
            const user = await axios.post(URL);
            dispatch(createUsersSuccess(user));
            dispatch(fetchUsers());
            dispatch(switchUserActions(false, false, false));
        } catch(error) {
            if (error && error.response && error.response.data)
                 error = error.response.data;
            if (error && error.data) {
                 error = error.data;
            }
            dispatch(createUsersFail(errors(error)));
            setTimeout(() => dispatch(createUsersFail(null)), 6000);
        }
    };
}
```